# Rebasing a patch without using git?

Tags: diff, patch

I've never used maintained files created with `patch` and `diff`. But what is the work flow when the `patch` drifts?  [As in this case](https://github.com/cpanel/docker-perl-compiler/issues/3). I can see the the failures when I do `-m` in the same format git would provide for resolution. But how can I, after I fix the problems, regenerate the patch with all the same information (notes and comments).

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "notes and comments". I looked at a patch created by git. There are additional information about a patch with hashes, commit message, git version, etc. Even if you manage to add some additional info to patch file, I do not think you can get a git hash. I would suggest just to use `diff` against previous version before patching and fixing the problems. You can apply that patch and then commit the changes with git. I guess you already knew that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `diff --unified file.orig file` after a `patch --merge` to create a new patch file based on the changed file without git. It won't have the same information, though.

Comment: Yep, I just found it. That was exactly what I need `--unified` on the diff.